# How to access web service from SSRS?

Tags: web-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008 R2 and am very new to web services.  I want to use the website:

```
https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/WebService/GeocoderService_V04_01.asmx
```

in order to translate addresses into geography datatypes.  How can I do this?  I would like to automate this process if possible.  I have found many websites which allow me to manually enter the addresses on their website, but I would like to be able to do this on my local desktop.  However, the website above supposedly will let me connect a web service to my local machine in order to do this translation.

What are the steps I need to take in order to add this web reference?  I tried following this website, but I haven't gotten it to work yet:

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129.aspx#repservxmlds_topic4
```

So I created an XML data source:
[image]

Then I created a new dataset using this datasource:

```
<Query>
   <Method Name="GeocodeAddressParsed" 
Namespace="https://geoservices.tamu.edu">
   <Parameters>
       <Parameter Name="City">       
       </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

But when I ran this query in BIDS, I got the following errors:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Unexpected or unimplemented census year: Unknown</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
----------------------------
Failed to execute web request for the specified URL.
Soap Fault:
Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Unexpected or unimplemented census year: Unknown
```

So I tried adding the censusYear parameter, but I continued to get this same error.  I also tried contacting ATM about this, but they were offline.  However, I don't think i need to contact them since the Service Description and method details are listed online.

I created all of this in the same project and RDL as my report.  I also tried creating this as a C# Console app.  But I prefer to run this from this same RDL file if possible.

I do not know why this didn't work.  I tried to simplify it as much as possible by only specifying one parameter.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Alright, I just updated my problem description.

Comment: I tried running the webservice directly from TAMU website but I still get error. Can you try and give some valid values for which this ws  works. https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/WebService/GeocoderService_V04_01.asmx?op=GeocodeAddressParsed